# Intellij GitToolBox Plugin Spawns dozens of ssh.exe that never close

Tags: intellij-idea

I just started at a new company and they use Intellij with the GitToolBox plugin. Their code is on BitBucket. I seem to be able to do everything manually so I think Git and the SSH stuff is all connected. When I open Intellij it opens up a dozen or more ssh.exe and maxes out my CPU (i9) and will stay that way forever until I manually kill them. When I try to fetch it also runs forever and never shows progress or completes. I verified that it is indeed the GitToolBox plugin as this issue does not occur when I remove that plugin. I have tried older versions as well as adding/removing the plugin.

The only thing I can see in the Intellij logs are repo hash mismatch INFO messages and the following:

```
2021-08-16 14:04:36,198 [ 557785]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionToolbarImpl - 'TodoViewToolbar' toolbar by default uses any focused component to update its actions. Toolbar actions that need local UI context would be incorrectly disabled. Please call toolbar.setTargetComponent() explicitly. 
java.lang.Throwable: toolbar creation trace
```

And

```
2021-08-16 14:04:59,580 [ 581167]   WARN - penapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils - Use DataManager.getDataContext(component) instead of SimpleDataContext for wrapping. 
java.lang.Throwable: Use DataManager.getDataContext(component) instead of SimpleDataContext for wrapping.
```

Has anyone encountered this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that happens upon this issue, I installed Git For Windows incorrectly and was using the "Git Bash only" option instead of the "Command line and 3rd party apps" option during the initial install. To change these you have to completely uninstall g4w and reinstall it selecting the new options.